# Why does RQM execution variables pass only null values to RFT using IVariablesManager?

Tags: c#, execution, rft

I have connected RQM to RFT via the default adapter.

On RQM, I have a test case and some test scripts for which I have created some execution variables at test case level.

The RQM successfully runs the RFT test on the local machine on which RFT is running.

The problem is that any reference to the execution variables from RQM only returns `null` values.

I am using the IVariablesManager interface.

The sample code is shown below.

What could be the problem?

Why is RQM passing only `null` values for the execution variables to RFT test scripts?

code below:
//RFT Script code below

```
//main or starting method in RFT
public void testMain(Object[] args){
    //Call the method that retrieves the execution variables
    getRQMVariable();
}

public void getRQMVariable(){
    try{
        IVariablesManager vm = getVariablesManager();
        IParameter _query = vm.getInputParameter("query");
        logInfo("Grab value of  RQM query : " + _query.getValue() ); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logInfo("Exception " + e.getMessage()+ " While fetching Execution variable input varaibles");
    } 
}
```

RQM test execution variable shown below
Image show the name of the Test case execution variables as "query"

Comment: You forgot the code

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Kindly check it out. Code is added.